# how do temporarily turn of vs-code error highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust-analyzer

VS Code error hi-lighting can offer quite a bit of clutter during code edits with its squiggles and colorization. It is a useful horn but once the problem is noticed it can become a nuisance that even makes it difficult to perceive the text and fix the problem. I don't think this feature was intended to get in the way.

Is there a convenient way to toggle VSCode error hi-lighting on and off without going through settings.json and playing with a bunch of flags?

Conclusion...

- Feature does not exist.
- Work around is to install and use the `When_File` VSCode extension to mask the error noise with less visible colors when the file has unsaved edits, as [clarified below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76391014/1612190).

Comment: I believe the older rust extension had a setting to control debounce time of code analysis, but when I looked through the settings of Rust Analyzer, it looks like it doesn't have something similar. Or maybe I just missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the extension [When File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.WhenFile)

Add this setting to your workspace `settings.json`

```json
  "whenFile.change": {
    "byLanguageId": {
      "rust": {
        "whenDirty": {
          "editorError.foreground": "#ff000020",
          "editorWarning.foreground": "#ff000020",
          "editorInfo.foreground": "#ff000020"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```